# The last month value of MoM quick measure in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a dataset up to Aug, 31st, 2020 and I use the quick measure MoM changes and got into a problem that my measure shows the MoM change in September, 2020 is -100% like below:
[Pict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyeeE.png)

I also wrote a Dax instead of quick measure but the result was the same, How can I hide the value of September 2020 ?
Thank guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your DAX, add IF to define when the revenue is blank. Formula would be:

```
MoM = IF(
      ISBLANK([Revenue]),BLANK(),
      "here the original MoM you calculated")
```